# How to see which commit a git submodule points at

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-commit

As far as I understand, if you add a submodule in git, then the main repo contains a pointer to a certain commit of the submodule.

Is there any way to see to which commit the main repo points at for a specific submodule, without checking out the code of the submodule?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sure; there are several ways:

1. `git ls-tree <commit> <relative path to submodule>`
2. `git ls-tree <commit>:<absolute path to parent of submodule>`
3. `git ls-tree <commit>:./<relative path to parent of submodule>`
4. `git ls-tree -r <commit> <relative path to parent of submodule>`

The first is easiest by far for checking a single submodule.

The second/third is easiest if you want to check several submodules contained in the same directory, but you don't want to recurse into any other subdirectories that are not submodules. (The `:` syntax uses the top level of the repository as its reference point by default, rather than your current working directory, so be sure to include the `./` prefix if you're way in the depths of your repo right now.)

The fourth is easiest if you have a lot of submodules, and only submodules, in a single directory.

Examples:

- `git ls-tree HEAD src/thirdparty/libfoo` shows the submodule and nothing else.
- `git ls-tree HEAD:src/thirdparty` gives you everything directly below `src/thirdparty`, including your submodule `src/thirdparty/libfoo`.
- `git ls-tree -r HEAD src/thirdparty` gives you everything directly below `src/thirdparty`, including your submodule `src/thirdparty/libfoo`, but will also recurse into `src/thirdparty/docs` which is actually a regular directory in your repo.
- `git ls-tree -r HEAD` lists absolutely everything in your repo, including submodules.

Submodules will show up as type `commit` (as opposed to the usual `blob` or `tree`).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (anymore?). I did `git ls-tree HEAD:some/path` (where some/path is a submodule) and git outputs `fatal: not a tree object`. I'm using git 2.25.0.

Comment: @mic you need to use `some`, then. I guess my example was a little hard to read, but the idea is to list the parent of the submodule, not the submodule itself.

Comment: @mic `git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep commit` a little work-around

Comment: `git ls-tree master <path>` worked for me with git 2.25.0

Comment: @mic, as SColvin says - i think it no longer requires the colon

Comment: The `fatal: not a tree object` is due to the syntax, you need to remove the colon `:`
The correct syntax is:
`git ls-tree HEAD src/thirdparty`

Like @MzA answered

Comment: @YuriNatividade the syntax with the `:` is correct, too; it just doesn't work if you put in the full path to the submodule. As my answer says, with this syntax you need to pass the *parent* of the submodule. For instance, if you have submodules below `src/thirdparty`, you have to pass `HEAD:src/thirdparty` and `HEAD:src/thirdparty/foo` will not work (because `foo` is a gitlink rather than a tree object). I may not have been aware of the colon-less syntax when writing my answer.

Answer (score 125):

As the other answers explain, you can use two commands:

- `git submodule status`, or
- `git ls-tree HEAD`, taking only the lines where the second column is `commit` (if you have awk you can use `git ls-tree HEAD | awk '$2 == "commit"'`).

### However, these commands give different results!

**What's the difference?**

- `git submodule status` **always reports the *current* status** (as the name suggests), that is, the commit that is currently checked-out. The hash that you see here is the same that you'd see by going into the submodule's directory<sup>1</sup> and checking the latest commit (with `git log`  or `git rev-parse HEAD`)
- `git ls-tree HEAD` **shows the *target* status**, which is not necessarily the current one. If you want to update your submodules so that they correspond to the specified version, you have to use `git submodule update`.

**What can cause the current and target status to differ?**

The typical situation in which they differ is when you `git checkout` another branch/tag/commit, or you use `git pull` to update your current branch. Both these commands will cause `HEAD` to be updated to the corresponding commit. Now, if this commit specifies that your submodule has to use a different version, `git submodule status` will still show the old one, but the target shown by `git ls-tree HEAD` will already be the new one.

**Is there a simpler way of noticing that they are out of sync?**

Check the output of `git submodule status`. [As the manual explains](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-status--cached--recursive--ltpathgt82308203), if there's a `+` before the hash, it means that the currently checked-out version and the target one are different.

**How do I bring them back in sync?**

By running `git submodule update`: the new submodule will be loaded, and both commands will indicate the same commit.

### Example

For example, let's say that in our repo we have a submodule called `base`.
The output of `git submodule status` is (notice the `+`):

> +059ca6c4940813aa956e8668cb0af27efa189b22 base (release-1.2)

And the output of `git ls-tree HEAD` is

> 160000 commit fbc447ef9468def36cf4089094d6960cc51618b3  base

As we can see, the hashes are different. In fact, the `+` had already informed us.

Now, if we type `git submodule update`, it says:

> Submodule path 'base': checked out 'fbc447ef9468def36cf4089094d6960cc51618b3'

And now all the commands we can use (`git submodule status`, `git ls-tree HEAD`, and `git log` from inside `base`) indicate `fbc447ef9468def36cf4089094d6960cc51618b3`, and there's no `+` in front of it in the output of `git submodule status`. If we run `git submodule update` again, nothing happens, as everything is already up to date, and there isn't even any output.

---

<sup>1</sup>: You have to be careful when you check the commit of a submodule, because it's tricky: to find the last commit that was made in submodule `base` you can't use `git log base`, you have to enter that directory (`cd base`) and then run `git log` from there. The reason is that the first command lists the commits of the "main" repository which set a new version of the submodule, and these commits are completely independent from those that were made inside the submodule.

Comment: instead of using awk to get the commit hash you can use `git ls-tree --object-only HEAD`

Comment: At least with git >= 2.36.0 I just noticed...

Answer (score 29):

A more straight-forward command would be:

`git submodule status`

Comment: This is great, just takes long if you have several submodules

Comment: @Ivan How many should I have to consider them "several"? 10? Just curious.

Comment: @antonimmo it of course also deppends on the size of each submodule and what kin dof computger you have I guess. In my case, I have 15 submodules of arround 100MB (~7000files). And it may take up to 2 minutes.

Comment: Umm, I didn't consider repo size, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 17):

Pardon for lurking, but I believe the answer to the original question is likely to be:

```
git submodule status --cached
```

"git submodule status" tells you which commit is checked out "--cached" tells you which commit a "git submodule update" would checkout.

I'm not sure when --cached was added to git.

Answer (score 3):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20656066) returns a 4-column output which contains the commit that a submodule gitlink points at. This is useful to verify that the pointed-to path is indeed a submodule, for example when that input user-provided in a script. To do that, verify that the second column is equal to "`commit`", e.g. using `awk`.

However, if this check is not required, a simpler output that has only the submodule commit and nothing else by one of

```
git rev-parse HEAD:./<relative-path>
git rev-parse HEAD:<repository-path>
```

where `<relative-path>` is the path to the submodule relative to the shell working directory and `<repository-path>` is the submodule path relative to the repository root. Instead of `HEAD`, any branch name, commit hash or other valid revision description (see `man git rev-parse`) can be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
git ls-tree -r <submodule-commitID-of-interest> <submodule-path> | awk '{print $3}'
```

Here a `bash` line to print submodule's repo commit IDs the last 10 submodule's commit IDs are pointing to:

```
git --no-pager log -10 --pretty="%H" <submodule-path> | while read i; do git ls-tree -r $I <submodule-path> | awk '{print $3}'; done
```