# Get the current commit id of specified submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want get the current commit id of the specified submodule. I thought when I cd into submodule directory and run `git rev-parse HEAD` i get this after I noticed this is a superproject current id.
Tried `git submodule status | grep <submodule_name>` also but its to slow to me. Any idea how to get this information little bit faster?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32327108/get-the-current-commit-id-of-specified-submodule/32327200#comment126532790_32327200) by [`brookbot`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9431020/brookbot), **[`git submodule status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-status--cached--recursive--ltpathgt82308203)** will print the SHA-1 of the currently checked out commit for each submodule, along with the submodule path and the output of git describe for the SHA-1.
See my [other answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60267524/6309).

---

You can start with [`git ls-files -s`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) (as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/460422/6309))

```
cd /path/to/parent/repo
git ls-files -s yourSubmodule
```

Note the absence of a trailing '`/`' after `yourSubmodule` (which is the root folder of the checked out submodule)

That will give the mode and sha1 associated with the **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index of the parent repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309))

```
160000 4d77d23305c5623356955ef9f908f4ec76780ba9 0       yourSubmodule
```

(The '0' is for [the stage number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1869991/6309))

Alternatives:

```
cd /path/to/repo/parentFolder/of/submodule

git ls-tree @ yourSubmodule
git rev-parse @:./yourSubmodule
```

The `rev-parse` only returns the submodule SHA1.

---

As commented by [heloman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2151275/heloman), you can also find the SHA1 with:

```
git rev-parse HEAD:path-to-your-sub-module
```

See more in "[How to see which commit a git submodule points at](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54238999/6309)".

Comment: Note (following the downvote): I forgot the `-s` in `git ls-file -s`. I have edited the answer and added two other alternatives.

Comment: `git rev-parse HEAD:path-to-your-sub-module` also works.

Comment: @heLomaN Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: `git submodule status` also works

Comment: @brookbot Thank you. Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 14):

Open your shell in the required project folder and then type the following `git` command:

```
git submodule
```

The resulting output would look like:

```
<module commit> <module-path> (<module-branch)
...
```

Comment: This is really <pre>git submodule status</pre> and documented in <pre>git help submodules</pre>

Answer (score 5):

```sh
git rev-parse HEAD:path/to/submodule
```

I've found this way better than accepted answer's alternatives for my automation usecase, as it outputs **only** the commit sha of an hipotetical `path/to/submodule`.

> **PS**: Credits and thanks to [heloman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2151275/heloman)

Comment: I have included the command in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> `git submodule status | grep <submodule_name>` also but its to **slow** to me

Starting with Git 2.16 (Q4 2017, two years after the OP's question), this should be faster (even though my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32327200/6309) remains a viable alternative).

See [commit a9f8a37](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9f8a37584a6d3e4702ce115476bebda20d871d3), [commit 9f580a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f580a6260ab301916286fb6ca05f6613e9904e8) (06 Oct 2017), and [commit 74a1064](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74a10642aa88c52ebb169489ea212a592d7bf3ce) (29 Sep 2017) by [Prathamesh Chavan (`pratham-pc`)](https://github.com/pratham-pc).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a1bf46e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1bf46ed9dfe67ce07f351e0fd9b9cfe68740d6c), 06 Nov 2017)</sup>

> ### [`submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9f8a37584a6d3e4702ce115476bebda20d871d3): port submodule subcommand 'status' from shell to C
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Stefan Beller</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Prathamesh Chavan</sup>
>
> This aims to make [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) 'status' a built-in. Hence, the function `cmd_status()` is ported from shell to C. This is done by introducing four functions: `module_status()`, `submodule_status_cb()`, `submodule_status()` and `print_status()`.
>
> The function `module_status()` acts as the front-end of the subcommand. It parses subcommand's options and then calls the function `module_list_compute()` for computing the list of submodules. Then this functions calls `for_each_listed_submodule()` looping through the list obtained.
>
> Then `for_each_listed_submodule()` calls `submodule_status_cb()` for each of the submodule in its list. The function `submodule_status_cb()` calls `submodule_status()` after passing appropriate arguments to the funciton. Function `submodule_status()` is responsible for generating the status each submodule it is called for, and then calls `print_status()`.
>
> Finally, the function `print_status()` handles the printing of submodule's status.
>
> Function `set_name_rev()` is also ported from [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) to the submodule--helper builtin function `compute_rev_name()`, which now generates the value of the revision name as required.

But.. The way "[`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) status" reports an initialized but not yet populated submodule has not been reimplemented correctly when a part of the "`git submodule`" command was rewritten in C, which has been corrected with Git 2.26 (Q1 2020)

See [commit f38c924](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f38c92452d0ad75b1c5c5cfdd04223ad7a9a08a9) (02 Feb 2020), and [commit 3b2885e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b2885ec9ba0b1328858231c9f5095e7f85d9f23), [commit ace912b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ace912bfb8e0cf85e29cc2d81fd847a96637be36) (24 Jan 2020) by [Peter Kaestle (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f2dcfcc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2dcfcc21d233c71e47e2ddae799968a18775a1d), 14 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b2885ec9ba0b1328858231c9f5095e7f85d9f23): fix status of initialized but not cloned submodules
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Peter Kaestle</sup>
>
> Original bash helper for "`submodule status`" was doing a check for initialized but not cloned submodules and prefixed the status with a minus sign in case no `.git` file or folder was found inside the submodule directory.
>
> This check was missed when the original port of the functionality from bash to C was done.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the pretiest, but if you cd `cd` into the subomdule, you can just `git log | head -1`