# Git recursive clone on a branch does not work

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to clone a specific branch of a repository with several git submodules, and having no luck with actually cloning them. I'm trying:

`git clone --recurse-submodules --branch myBranch -j8 https://github.com/me/myrepo`

But, all the submodule folders are empty, even after cloning start.

Also trying `git submodule update`, `git submodule sync`...but nothing works, and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Can you point us at a specific repository so that we can try to reproduce the exact problem? Are you running `git submodule init` before `git submodule update` (or alternately, `git submodule update --init`)?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure those submodules are there in mybranch:

- check the `.gitmodules` file
- check the [output of `git ls-files -s aSubmoduleFolder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32327200/6309) (no trailing slash)

If there is no submodule entry, that would explain why they are empty.
If they are, as commented, a `git submodule update --init` should be enough.