# How is it possible to get the current commit id of a submodule in git?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I would like to find out the current commit id of a submodule. I've found this answer about [current commit id of specified submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32327108/get-the-current-commit-id-of-specified-submodule) It suggests this code:

```sh
git rev-parse @:./yourSubmodule
```

It works, but if I update the submodule, it still gives me the old commit id:

```sh
git submodule update --remote --merge

git rev-parse @:./yourSubmodule
```

`git submodule status` gives me the correct commit id, but the result is not just the commit id, but some auxiliary informations as well:

```
git submodule status | grep yourSubmodule
```

Result:

```
+1b2377f523dca6fa0c49bd7fa56eeb32011774e1 yourSubmodule (remotes/origin/HEAD)
```

What is the correct way, to determine the current commit id of a submodule? Only the commit id is needed, nothing else.

Comment: `(cd path/to/submodule && git rev-parse HEAD)`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am afraid that from the superproject you cannot retrieve that information using a simple git command with some option. The first command you found

```
git rev-parse @:./yourSubmodule
```

refers to the submodule gitlink in the index of the `HEAD` (`@`) revision. However it cannot work in your case because you have not even staged the submodule update. As @torek wrote in the comments, the probably easier way is to run `rev-parse` from your submodule directory, like this

```
git -C ./yourSubmodule rev-parse HEAD
```

But there are several other ways to do this:

- `sed`ding from `git submodule status`

  ```
  git submodule status | sed -n 's/+\(\w*\) yourSubmodule.*/\1/p'
  ```
- DO NOT DO THIS, but that info is stored in the `.git` repository at `.git/modules/yourSubmodule/refs/heads/master` before being staged. You can obviously find it elsewhere, for example in `FETCH_HEAD`, logs folder ecc.
- Instead, when you stage the submodule reference update, you can retrieve it using a syntax similar to the one that you initially tried:

  ```
  git rev-parse :0:./yourSubmodule
  ```

  that 0 between `:` is the [revision](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtltpathgtemegemHEADREADMEememmasterREADMEem) for the stage.

By the way, it is weird that git does not provide a way to retrieve that from the superproject using some subcommand of `git submodule`, I am still doubtful that I missed it.